# UWP : How to get new size of shape after rotation?

Tags: uwp, geometry, windows-10-universal

How to measure its width and height after rotation in UWP? It can be any shape, such as a polygon or ellipse.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate coordinates of extremal points.

For polygons

```
left = min(p[i].x)
right = max(p[i].x)
top = min(p[i].y)
bottom = max(p[i].y)
```

For ellipse or another analytical curves  get extremal coordinates analytically

```
solve X'(t) = 0 for t=tz   
(there are some subtle moments for min/max finding through derivatives)
find min and max from X(tz) and curve ends and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to compute the bounding box from the XAML visual tree. I normally use Win2D for these types of operations. Have a look at [CanvasGeometry](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Geometry_CanvasGeometry.htm) and its ability to compute a bounding box.

If you don't have access to Win2D or you just need a quick solution to this problem, here's a helper class that should work on any shape, ellipse, path, etc:

**Warning:** this is a poor implementation that uses brute force hit-testing. I've added a timer to prove how slow it is.

```
public static class BoundsHelper
{
    /// <summary>Computes the axis-aligned minimum bounding box of the given <paramref name="element"/>.</summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element to test.</param>
    /// <param name="tolerance">The precision tolerance expressed in pixels. The lower the value the higher the precision, but the slower the operation.</param>
    public static Rect ComputeBounds(FrameworkElement element, float tolerance = .5f)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var transform = element.TransformToVisual(null);
        var bounds = new Rect(0, 0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);

        bounds = transform.TransformBounds(bounds);

        var minX = TestX(element, bounds, tolerance);
        var minY = TestY(element, bounds, tolerance);
        var maxX = TestX(element, bounds, -tolerance);
        var maxY = TestY(element, bounds, -tolerance);

        sw.Stop();

        Debug.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms to compute bounds with tolerance = {tolerance}");


        return new Rect(new Point(minX, minY), new Point(maxX, maxY));
    }

    private static double TestX(UIElement element, Rect bounds, float tolerance)
    {
        bounds = tolerance > 0
            ? new Rect(bounds.Left, bounds.Top, tolerance, bounds.Height)
            : new Rect(bounds.Right + tolerance, bounds.Top, -tolerance, bounds.Height);

        while (!VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(bounds, element).Any())
        {
            bounds.X += tolerance;
        }

        return bounds.X;
    }

    private static double TestY(UIElement element, Rect bounds, float tolerance)
    {
        bounds = tolerance > 0
            ? new Rect(bounds.Left, bounds.Top, bounds.Width, tolerance)
            : new Rect(bounds.Left, bounds.Bottom + tolerance, bounds.Width, -tolerance);

        while (!VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(bounds, element).Any())
        {
            bounds.Y += tolerance;
        }

        return bounds.Y;
    }
}
```